# Can I search for users GitHub or Twitter info in Data.SE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm curious if I can find users in [Data Explorer](https://s.tk/data) by their GitHub username or Twitter handle.

I know I can find users from their **Location** (`Location`) or their **Website link** (`WebsiteUrl`).

[image]

Is there a way to find them based off of **Twitter username** or **GitHub username**?

---

Here's the query I came up with so far (using `AboutMe`), but I verified that it doesn't actually check the GitHub link, rather it checks just the whole About me (not including the GH or Twitter link)

```
SELECT u.Id as [User Link]
FROM Users u
WHERE AboutMe LIKE '%' + ##userName:string## + '%'
ORDER BY CreationDate DESC
```

---

#### Edit

Not a duplicate of [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333840/358161), I'm specifically asking about the fields for Twitter and GH username.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible; these fields simply aren't in the database schema, as documented here: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede). The [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) doesn't expose them either.

I suppose you could write a query which checks for GitHub links in the `AboutMe` field, e.g. `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE AboutMe LIKE '%<a href="https://github.com/"%'` but those are more likely to yield links to actual GitHub *projects* since people tend to use the dedicated field for their GitHub account itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming github URLs are in this format:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{projectname}
```

```
https://github.com/orgs/{orgName}/{projectname}
```

If that's the case, then using @Glorfindel's suggestion above would do the job so long as the first argument in the query URL isn't `/orgs/`, and the `{projectname}` argument shouldn't be used either, otherwise it's most likely the developer is mentioning a project, not a profile of a person.